# Python converting to exe including libraries?

Tags: python, exe, libraries

So, I'm making a text based RPG in Python and I've converted the project to exe before but my question is, is there a way to make sure the libraries I've added work with the exe without the user needing python or the libraries? The ones in question are primarily colorama and termcolor. I use them to make different rarities of items colored and I'd like the user to be able to see that too. Ive tried this and the colors do not work on a separate computer I've used.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents.  There are lots of ways to do this and I mean lots.  But none come close to the true power of pyinstaller.

[image]

Choose pyinstaller because:

It has an updating feature (see pyupdater)

You can use colorama with it

For some reason I will never understand, people still use cxfreeze which is updated less regularly and you can't even provide updates to users.

CxFreeze used to have Esky, but even they recommend pyinstaller and pyupdater.  Go figure!

Comment: My personal choice as well. But I do worry this Q will illicit a lot of opinion

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use Python [Disutils](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/index.html#distutils-index). Python maintains these tools to help developers easily distribute code to users, and I think they will do what you are searching for. In particular, see [10.43](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.command.install_lib).